# Backward foramatting values in VST GUI

Tags: user-interface, plugins, vst

A new problem to solve.

In my my setParameter() i use to set values up to "real values". 
I'm formatting them with `value * (max - min) + min`
e.g.: `value of 1.0 == 20000Hz` or `value of 0.0 == -30dB`

Now I have the problem, that VSTGUI seems to accept only values from 0-1.
Is there a better solution than rewrite all the Code in the setParameter()?

Something like sprintf() maybe?

EDIT: I'm using the CAnimKnob Class.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? Your process of adjusting `value` with `max` and `min` will already change a [0,1] value into a different range...

Comment: I am setting values for an EQ in my setParameter Class in VST SDK. 
I do this in ranges of 20 Hz between 20000 Hz. Not between 0 and 1.

Comment: Well can't you just perform the reverse operation? `(value - min) / (max - min)`? That will give you back a number between 0 and 1...

Comment: That was my first thought. But: I haven't found out if this will work with the CAnimKnob Class in VST GUI.

Comment: ... why don't you try it and see?

Comment: 'Cause I don't know how to use it on CAnimKnob Class.

Answer (score 0):

aardvark's comment is correct, the reverse option is what you want here. Having worked with vstgui in the past I can verify that this will work.

I just wanted to add that if you are using such an algorithm for frequency, it will be very difficult for the user. You should instead use a logarithmic scale so that it is easier to select higher frequencies. Otherwise a single step of the knob will result in a difference of several hundred Hertz as you approach 20kHz.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this advice. That's what I do first if I know how to use the reverse operator with VSTGUI. VSTGUI CAnimKnob accepts only float values from 0.0 to 1.0. Doesn't matter if linear or logarithmic. For a better understanding here some code fragments:

I call the process function like this:

```
case kFreq1: fFreq1 = value * (fFreqMax - fFreqMin) + fFreqMin;break;
case kGain1: fGain1 = value * (fGainMax - fGainMin) + fGainMin;break;
case kQ1 : fQ1 = value * (fQMax - fQMin) + fQMin;break;
```

That's 'cause my filter code work with the values 20 - 20000 for frequency and -30 to 30 for Gain.

The Knob in VSTGUI gives only values from 0 to 1 and get only values from 0 to 1.

So the main question is: WHERE to bring back the `float values 0-1` from `20 - 20000` in the code?